# Do the Quincy know of the consequences of their power?

Tags: bleach

We know that when a Quincy kills a Hollow, they destroy its soul and cause an imbalance that could destroy Soul Society and the material world if done enough.

Are the Quincy aware of this fact? If so, why do they persist in killing Hollows?

Comment: Something to do with Pride as i recall. Who would want to let such monsters run around and kill when they could do something about it. Uryu was well aware of it however, and even sided with the shinigami until his grandfather was killed thanks to Miyuri. THen he just hated both sides.

Comment: IIRC before the genocide, the Shinigami informed the Quincy that their power caused such problem. The Quincy was either ignored it or disbelief it. There was also the problem of, "the Shinigami didn't come quick enough so we decided to kill the Hollow ourself to prevent casualties."

@Ryan when was it mentioned that Uryu sided with the Shinigami before his granpa got killed? IIRC he was indifferent towards the Shinigami before that accident.

Comment: @AyaseEri Ichigo found out about what happened to the quincy, and then went directly to confront uryu about it. Uryu indeed does not care about shinigami, even viewing them as unnecessary, but regarding the incident 200 years earlier, he said "As for the story of their fall, I fell the shinigami were probably right, until my sensei died right before my eyes"(in the translation i found, chapter 46, pg 10). After that, he hated the shinigami for wronging him and his grandfather, though he never expressed sympathy for the past Quincy either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They were acutely aware of this fact.  From [the Bleach Wiki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Quincy#Fall_of_the_Quincy), emphasis mine:

> Since the origin of the Quincy, many years passed within Soul Society trying to appeal to the Quincy that the **handling of Hollows should be left to the Shinigami**. **The Quincy refused to accept the situation**. As time went on, the number of Quincy increased and the cycle of souls became more unstable, forcing the Shinigami to reluctantly wipe out the Quincy in order to maintain the balance of the world.

From this, I gather:

- The Quincy may not have originally been aware of what their powers were doing.
- They learned the true consequences after the Soul Reapers attempted some kind of negotiations with them to get them to leave Hollows to them.
- They *disregarded the consequences* and continued to use their powers against Hollows, due to (often) slow responses from Soul Reapers.